# Trouble going from CuDNNLSTM into a Dense Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've got a bit of an issue that I have spent far too long on. I've read so much documentation and watched so many tutorials on this and do not understand why when I modify my network from examples people have shown and feed my own data in it just always hates it!

I have a data set that is of shape:

```
train_X.shape = (312,5000,7)
train_Y.shape = (312,5000,1)
```

I have it in the correct sequence (312 samples, 5000 time steps, 7 data channels). Then I have created a label set for each of those 312 samples that just says 0 or 1 if it is what I want or not. This is VERY similar to the activation word work done out of Coursera, but I am not trying to use speech or audio at all, this is sensor data (time driven sensor data).

I have 2 questions, and I think if anyone can answer the first one I can probably figure it out, or if you just can see why I am failing here that would also be appreciated.

I've decided to build a model that is fairly deep (my shallow ones were performing poorly) and also redesigned it from the original. My issue is that it no longer likes dimensions at all.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(LSTM_units,
                  input_shape = (x_train.shape[1:]),
                  return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(DR))

model.add(CuDNNLSTM(LSTM_units,
                   return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(DR))

model.add(CuDNNLSTM(LSTM_units))
model.add(Dropout(DR))    

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(DR))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

My compile works just fine, it's happy and gives me a summary detailing that my model will slowly go from (None, 5000, 18) --> (None, 128) at the end of the LSTM and then to a (None, 32) --> (None, 2) as I have 2 classes (0 or 1).

Upon trying to fit the model of course I am then told that:

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_14 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (312, 5000, 1)
```

I've tried to reshape my matrix on passing it to the dense layer but that just doesn't seem to work at all...

So my question is this:
1) What am I doing wrong here in terms of building my model?

2) Is there a way to... print the tensor sizes as each step takes place that isn't in the model.summary command?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution here

[Incompatible dense layer error in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544894/incompatible-dense-layer-error-in-keras?rq=1)

I don't think I can mark mine as a duplicate question... Essentially the issue I was having was that I was asking the network to give me an output of (batch_size, 2) when in reality I wanted to get an answer for EVERY data point along the input!

I combined bad practices from several tutorials all into one to give me a ton of issues. Hopefully this helps anyone with the same issue. Also my updated code is posted below.

```
def create_model(x_train, GRU_units,DR):
model = Sequential()
print("Adding first layer...")
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(GRU_units,
                  input_shape = (x_train.shape[1:]),
                  return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(DR))
print(model.output_shape)

print("Adding second layer...")
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(GRU_units,
                   return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(DR))
print(model.output_shape)

print("Adding third layer...")
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(GRU_units, 
                    return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(DR))
print(model.output_shape)    

print("Adding fourth layer (Dense 32)...")
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(32, activation='relu')))
model.add(Dropout(DR))
print(model.output_shape)

print("Adding output layer...")
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
print(model.output_shape)

return model
```